# How to access an object/var from view1 but instantiated in view2 in Backbone js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

I am trying to access an object(*this.historyComboBox*) declared in a view(*StatusView*)'s *render* function and trying to access the same object from another view(*HistoryView*)'s *extendedEvents* function.
I have tried to use *this.historyComboBox* to access it but unable to hold any reference. Got really puzzled. If anyone has got some different idea I am ready to try it out!

Note: StatusView gets initialized prior to HistoryView.

Following is the code snippet.

```
StatusView = Backbone.View.extend({
    init: function() {
                //some code
    },
    render: function() {
        this.historyComoBox = new sys.ComboBox();
    }
}

HistoryView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template(historyTemplate),
    init: function() {
        //some code
    },

    extendedEvents: {
        'click #refreshButton': function() {
            //want to access historyComoBox; not accessible with 'this.historyComoBox'
        }
    }               
}
```

Comment: `historyComoBox` is a property of status views. But you haven't instantiated any status view object (at least in the code snippet). Therefore there isn't any `historyComoBox` to access.

Answer (score 1):

To get a property of a `StatusView` instance, you need a reference to that instance. So, if you have something like this:

```
var statusView = new StatusView();
```

Then from within the methods of `HistoryView`, you can do this:

```
statusView.historyComboBox;
```

However, while you *can* do it this way, I wouldn't access the `StatusView` instance directly like this. A better way would be to pass it to the `HistoryView` instance as a parameter, which you would receive in the `initialize` method. This keeps the views loosely coupled,

```
var HistoryView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function (options) {
    this.statusView = options.statusView; 
  },
  events: {
    'click #refreshButton': function () {
      // use this.statusView;
    }
  }
});
```

(I notice you're using the names `init` and `extendedEvents`. You don't mention that you're using a third-party library with Backbone or something else that might change those, so I'll just mention that Backbone expects these to be `initialize` and `events` respectively.)